# Rank Visits SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a sample table of doctor visits by ID. I'm looking to rank the problems by age, partitioned by ID so I can do some statistic calculations on the 2nd and 3rd visit of the same problem by ID. Please Note: I have a larger dataset so i'm looking for something that will handle that.

So far I have

```
SELECT 
    ID, Age, Problem, COUNT(Problem) AS cnt,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Problem, Age ASC) AS rnk
FROM
    #Test1
GROUP BY
    ID, Problem, Age
ORDER BY
    Age ASC
```

The code runs but the rank is not properly calculated. Please help.

Comment: What is your expected output with your sample data? Fill your rank you want, and the count you want plz.

Comment: expected:
1,2,1,1,3,1,1,2,1,1,2,1

Comment: theoretically, I want rank to label all the occurrences of problem by id, so that i can pull the second occurrence of a problem(s) if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need partition by ID and Problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test1 (ID int, Problem nvarchar(20), Age int)

INSERT INTO #Test1
VALUES
(1,'Arm',50),
(1,'Arm',52),
(1,'Foot',54),
(1,'Tongue',55),
(1,'Arm',59),
(2,'Toe',60),
(2,'Toe',60),
(2,'Arm',61),
(3,'Tooth',75),
(3,'Tooth',76),
(3,'Knee',78)

SELECT 
    ID, 
    Age, 
    Problem, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Problem, Age) as cnt,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Problem ORDER BY Age) as rnk
FROM #Test1 AS t
ORDER BY  t.Age

DROP TABLE #Test1
```

In this solution you will get the same rank = 1 for data (2,'Toe',60). To enumerate them, replace `RANK` with `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: let me try this out real quick

Comment: @KID_J have you solved your problem? Can you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) instead of [**`rank()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx):

```
select 
    id 
  , Age
  , Problem
  , cnt = count(*) over (partition by id, Problem) 
  , rnk = row_number() over (partition by id, Problem order by Age) 
from t
order by id, Age, Problem
```

test setup: http://rextester.com/DUWG50873

returns:

```
+----+-----+---------+-----+-----+
| id | Age | Problem | cnt | rnk |
+----+-----+---------+-----+-----+
|  1 |  50 | Arm     |   3 |   1 |
|  1 |  52 | Arm     |   3 |   2 |
|  1 |  54 | Foot    |   1 |   1 |
|  1 |  55 | Tongue  |   1 |   1 |
|  1 |  59 | Arm     |   3 |   3 |
|  2 |  60 | Toe     |   2 |   1 |
|  2 |  60 | Toe     |   2 |   2 |
|  2 |  61 | Arm     |   1 |   1 |
|  3 |  75 | Tooth   |   2 |   1 |
|  3 |  76 | Tooth   |   2 |   2 |
|  3 |  78 | Knee    |   1 |   1 |
+----+-----+---------+-----+-----+
```